# Is there a way to access constants of a (java) class by an alias in scala?

Tags: scala

I would like to make a short alias for a java class.

Is there a way to import (or make a type alias to) a java class (e.g. `HttpServletResponse`), and access its constant values (e.g. `HttpServletResponse`) using the alias?

Type alias works fine, but I cannot find a way to access the constants of the class.

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry I asked a wrong question. I knew importing with a short name works.

What I like to do is avoid writing `import ...{HttpServletResponse => Response}` every file in which `MyHttpServlet` is mixed-in.

Type aliases in `MyHttpServlet` makes it possible without importing, but accessing constants is still the issue. (or maybe it's impossible?)

```
trait MyHttpServlet extends HttpServlet {
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

  // works
  type Response = HttpServletResponse

  // compile error: object creation impossible, since it has 36 unimplemented members.
  //object Response extends HttpServletResponse

  def notAllowed(response: Response): Unit = {
    // works
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    // I would like to do something like this
    //response.setStatus(Response.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the import.

```
import javax.servlet.http.{HttpServletResponse => Response}

response.setStatus(Response.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Type aliases don't allow static member access because one can't call members on a *type* in scala, it is only possible on values.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But I failed to express my issue correctly. I edited the question. Sorry :-(

Comment: @n4to4 thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, although java interop is great in Scala, there's no way to treat a parent `enum` instance as a value - Java classes with static members are _not_ treated as scala `object`s, so there's no way to do the trick other than renaming the import.

Comment: I see. Thanks again.